# Price with , in VARCHAR to DECIMAL

Tags: mysql, sql

In my SQL database I have the prices in VARCHAR but I've problem when I try to order by price..
I have try to use this query but doesn't work..!

```
CAST(price AS DECIMAL) DESC
```

If I launch this query the result order is:

```
1.123,45
122,00
2.543,21
656,00
etc
```

Comment: You should use the correct datatype to start with, then you'll never have this problem. "doesn't work" is not a problem description. Does it throw an error? If so, what is the error? Are the results unexpected? If so, what do you expect?

Comment: When storing numbers as varchar in a database, this is usually because the column contains a string formatted for display. The database is oblivious to its content and not supposed to do any calculation on it. If you need something to calculate with in a database store a number instead.

Comment: Perhaps decimal point is expected, instead of decimal comma.

Comment: Maybe is not well aligned, but it is ordered correctly .

Comment: @McNets: 2.00 between 123.45 and 543.21?

Comment: Store prices using an appropriate data type.

Answer (score 1):

Use a replace to create a decimal point, then cast it with the precision and scale...

```
cast(replace(Price, ',', '.') as decimal(9,2))
```

Comment: Doesn't look great to me. You rely on the writing process to always use a comma for a decimal separator which is subject to change. And what to do when a number additionally contains a thousand separator? Then you rely on database settings to take the point for the decimal separator which may also change. I think the best advice would be to sort the values where the values are written and the complete format thus known (i.e. some app or business layer) or to store numbers instead in the first place.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Of course, storing numbers as numbers is the most sensible solution. I hadn't considered thousands separators.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the direct "convert" in order by

> `ORDER BY convert( [name column], decimal)`

Answer (score 0):

I have find the problem.. The numbers > of 999,99 ha the . under the miles..
For example:
1.000,00
I have replaced all . with this query:

```
UPDATE computers SET prezzo = REPLACE(prezzo, '.', '')
```

Comment: If you are free to change the strings's format, why can't you change it's datatype? This would be a solution, while what you are showing is nothing more than a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Create a one example as per bolow:

## Create a table

```
create table table1(
id integer,
price varchar(20)
)
```

## Insert record price into varchar:

```
insert into table1 values(1, '10.1');
insert into table1 values(1, '100.1');
insert into table1 values(1, '20.1');
insert into table1 values(1, '200.1');
```

## Sorting on varchar price as per numeric field:

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` order by cast(replace(price, ',', '.') as decimal(9,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that if your commas are thousands separators then you need to replace them with empty strings. If your commas are decimal separators then you need to replace them with decimal points.

Try this if your commas are thousands separators:

```
SELECT
    price
FROM
    prices
ORDER BY
    CAST(REPLACE(price,',','') AS DECIMAL)
```

This should give you:

```
price
543,21
123,45
1,001
6,00
2,00
```

If your commas are decimal separators then this:

```
SELECT
    price
FROM
    prices
ORDER BY
    CAST(REPLACE(price,',','.') AS DECIMAL)
```

Will give you:

```
price
543,21
123,45
6,00
2,00
1,001
```

Answer (score 0):

Check This.

```
select * ,REPLACE( price, ',', '' )  from money
order by CAST(REPLACE(price,',','') AS DECIMAL)
```

Check Demo Here : [Link](http://rextester.com/CXQ94647)